# If I am manipulating the DOM with vanilla JS... can I make one of those items a React component?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I've got an applet right now that builds a table of TODOs using vanilla JS.

Is it possible to add a React component button to one of those TODOs? Specifically trying to update the button, but React does not like you manipulating the DOM manually... so is this even doable? I thought it was possible to have React alongside other code. I've seen static examples such as [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html) in their docs, but nothing dynamic like this.

e.g.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    fetch('/getTodos')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data)
        loadTodos(data)
    })
})

function loadTodos(data) {

    const table = document.getElementById("todos-list")

    if (data.length === 0) { return table.innerHTML = "<tr><td>Nothing to do!</td></tr>" }

    let content = ""

    data.forEach( ({id,todo,dueDate}) => {
        content += `<tr><td>${todo}</td></tr>`
        content += `<tr><td>${new Date(dueDate).toLocaleString()}</td></tr>`
        content += `<tr><td><button class="delete-btn" data-id=${id} onclick='deleteMe(${id})'>Delete</button></td></tr>`
    })

    table.innerHTML = content

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can dynamically insert a React component into an existing container easily enough:

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  // simulating async api call
  const table = document.getElementById("todos-list");
  table.innerHTML = `
  <tbody>
  <tr><td class="target"></td><td>another td</td></tr>
  <tr><td>another row</td></tr>
  </tbody>
  `;
  ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.target'));
}, 500);


const App = () => {
    return <span><button>Dynamic Component</button></span>;
};
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<table id='todos-list'></div>
```

But other than populating container(s), there's no sane way to turn *existing* elements into React elements. Your `<button class="delete-btn" data-id=${id} onclick='deleteMe(${id})'>Delete</button>` can't be turned into a component (though with some ugly code you could have a separate React component that adds a click listener to it... but don't do that). In React, you should always start with a container or few that you then insert your app's components into.

Comment: Yeah, right. I'd put a <div> or other element to replace instead of the Delete Me button.

This is .jsx though.. or it'd require Babel given the markup. How would I incorporate that into an existing .js file?

If I include the following, the DOM manipulation with innerHTML doesn't actually work.
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel" src="index.js"></script>

Comment: Actually it's more appropriate to say that the document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ... ) call doesn't actually fire if I load the scrip using babel. I don't get why.

Comment: The document's probably already been loaded - check `document.readyState` to see if you can run your code immediately or if you need to wait

Comment: Ok, sorted that out, thanks. Saw that in another comment. Now I'm only seeing the first instance of the <div id="react-button"></div> replaced by the React component. Not one for each TODO.

Comment: And how would I pass params into the React component?

Comment: If you want one for each, loop over the elements - `querySelectorAll` or whatever you want. To pass info in, use props. `ReactDOM.render(<MyButton someProp="foo" />`

Comment: But this is a really bad idea. Better to render the whole list as React than try what you're doing.

Comment: commentsList.innerHTML = content

  const delete_buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-react')
  delete_buttons.forEach((button) => {
    ReactDOM.render(<ReactButton id={button.id} />, document.querySelector(`.btn-react`));
  })  

}

const ReactButton = ({id}) => {
  console.log(`react button made`)

  const clicky = () => {
    console.log(id)
  }

  return <span><button onClick={clicky}>React</button></span>
}

This is replacing the first button with id = 2, although I see both 'rendering'. I feel like I'm close but not quite there.

Comment: You probably want to change `document.querySelector('.btn-react')` to `button` to target the element in the loop - but again, please don't do this, render the whole list in React to begin with and you'll have far fewer headaches

Comment: I was going to add an Edit button, too, so I didn't want to make it that generic. This is more of an exercise in what's possible. Trying to understand embedding React better. I built this all in React much more easily and surely that's the better solution. Appreciate the help.

Comment: I'm just not sure why it's only grabbing the first instance of .btn-react and not the second. They both appear in the DOM, and I see ReactButton triggered twice, but the second instance of .btn-react is just empty. And the first instance is logging the ID of the second one (2), even if itself has ID = 1. It seems like some screwy lifted state.

Comment: Target the element in the loop by using the loop parameter `button` instead of `querySelector`. `querySelector` will give you the first matching element in the DOM (if called from `document`)

Comment: D'oh, I misunderstood at first. Yeah that was dumb of me. Thank you!